# PHPUnit how to test a specific method with specific parameter with specific answer for more than one call

Tags: php, phpunit

I have tried testing multiple parameters for a specific method, and get different answers by the same mock for different parameters.

This is what I've done so far:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('MyClass')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

$mock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('myMethod')
            ->with($this->equalTo('param1'))
            ->will($this->returnValue('test1'));
$mock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('myMethod')
            ->with($this->equalTo('param2'))
            ->will($this->returnValue('test2'));
```

When I call `$myClass->myMethod('param1')` all is well and I get the `'test1'`

**However, here's the problem:**

When I call `$myClass->myMethod('param2')` I get an error

> Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
>   --- Expected
>   +++ Actual @@ @@
>   -'param1'
>   +'param2'

A solution I have found is to just create a new mock for each call.

```
$mock1 = $this->getMockBuilder('MyClass')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();        
$mock1->expects($this->any())
    ->method('myMethod')
    ->with($this->equalTo('param1'))
    ->will($this->returnValue('test1'));

$mock2 = $this->getMockBuilder('MyClass')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
$mock2->expects($this->any())
    ->method('myMethod')
    ->with($this->equalTo('param2'))
    ->will($this->returnValue('test2'));
```

I do not know though why is this needed, perhaps I am using it wrong.

So the question remains:

**How do I mock the same class, with a specific method, for different parameters and get different return values?**

Comment: Which version of PHPUnit are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's about dependency for a tested class, that is called twice inside tested method then it could be made like this

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('MyClass')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

$mock->expects($this->at(0))
            ->method('myMethod')
            ->with($this->equalTo('param1'))
            ->will($this->returnValue('test1'));
$mock->expects($this->at(1))
            ->method('myMethod')
            ->with($this->equalTo('param2'))
            ->will($this->returnValue('test2'));
```

The first time it must be called with arg `param1` then `$mock->myMethod('param1')` and will return `test1`, second - with arg `param2` and will return `test2`.

Comment: It did help, however I had to use at(0) at both of them.
Any idea why?

Comment: To be honest, don't know why. Maybe, it counts calls with same arg? Try to debug it

Comment: @JacobCohen Did you implement Dmitry's suggestion, of having a single mock object instead of 2 separate mock objects?  If not, you should.

Comment: Yeah I did, and as I mentioned, it only worked when I used $this->at(0) on both expectations.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simplify these statements a bit.  If all you're needing to do is mock the function so that when you pass 'param1' you get back 'test1', then this should work:

```
$mock->method('myMethod')
    ->with('param1')
    ->willReturn('test1');

$mock->method('myMethod')
    ->with('param2')
    ->willReturn('test2');
```

Comment: Doesn't work for the param2

It says expectation failed and that failed to assert that two strings are equal...